# How to stop a pm2 process from systemctl

Tags: pm2, systemctl

Here is my service file

```
[Unit]
Description=HTTP Hello World
After=network.target
[Service]
User=mukund
Environment=MY_HOST=localhost
WorkingDirectory=/home/mukund/Work/nodejs/nodeExpTutorial
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pm2 start config.json
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

where config.json is

```
{"apps" : [
    {

      "script"     : "app.js",
      "instances"  : 3,
      "exec_mode"  : "cluster"
    }]
}
```

when i run this command i am getting this error

```
mukund@mukund-ThinkPad-E15:~/Work/nodejs/nodeExpTutorial$ systemctl status demo-node-app.service
● demo-node-app.service - HTTP Hello World
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/demo-node-app.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-08-07 19:09:00 IST; 13s ago
    Process: 38182 ExecStart=/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 config.json (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 38182 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 07 19:08:59 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 systemd[1]: Started HTTP Hello World.
Aug 07 19:09:00 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38182]: [PM2][ERROR] Command not found
Aug 07 19:09:00 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38182]: usage: pm2 [options] <command>
Aug 07 19:09:00 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38182]: pm2 -h, --help             all available commands and options
Aug 07 19:09:00 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38182]: pm2 examples               display pm2 usage examples
Aug 07 19:09:00 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38182]: pm2 <command> -h           help on a specific command
Aug 07 19:09:00 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38182]: Access pm2 files in ~/.pm2
Aug 07 19:09:00 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 systemd[1]: demo-node-app.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 07 19:09:00 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 systemd[1]: demo-node-app.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

then i changed the service script to this

```
[Unit]
Description=HTTP Hello World
After=network.target
[Service]
User=mukund
Environment=MY_HOST=localhost
WorkingDirectory=/home/mukund/Work/nodejs/nodeExpTutorial
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pm2 start start config.json
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

reloaded the serveice

```
mukund@mukund-ThinkPad-E15:~/Work/nodejs/nodeExpTutorial$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

started the service again

```
mukund@mukund-ThinkPad-E15:~/Work/nodejs/nodeExpTutorial$ sudo systemctl start demo-node-app.service
```

then on the status i got this success message

```
mukund@mukund-ThinkPad-E15:~/Work/nodejs/nodeExpTutorial$ sudo systemctl status demo-node-app.service
● demo-node-app.service - HTTP Hello World
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/demo-node-app.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2020-08-07 19:10:02 IST; 20s ago
    Process: 38359 ExecStart=/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 start config.json (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 38359 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38359]: [PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [app](ids: [ 0 ])
Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38359]: [PM2] [app](0) ✓
Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38359]: ┌─────┬───────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬─────>
Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38359]: │ id  │ name      │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu >
Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38359]: ├─────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼─────>
Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38359]: │ 0   │ app       │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 38367    │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%  >
Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38359]: │ 1   │ config    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ N/A      │ 0      │ 0    │ stopped   │ 0%  >
Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38359]: └─────┴───────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴─────>
Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38359]: [PM2][WARN] Current process list running is not in sync with saved list. Type 'pm2 save' to synch>
Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 systemd[1]: demo-node-app.service: Succeeded.
```

I got the app started but i cannot use the stop command to stop it

```
mukund@mukund-ThinkPad-E15:~/Work/nodejs/nodeExpTutorial$ sudo systemctl stop demo-node-app.service
mukund@mukund-ThinkPad-E15:~/Work/nodejs/nodeExpTutorial$ sudo systemctl status demo-node-app.service
● demo-node-app.service - HTTP Hello World
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/demo-node-app.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2020-08-07 19:10:02 IST; 45s ago
    Process: 38359 ExecStart=/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 start config.json (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 38359 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38359]: [PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [app](ids: [ 0 ])
Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38359]: [PM2] [app](0) ✓
Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38359]: ┌─────┬───────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬─────>
Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38359]: │ id  │ name      │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu >
Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38359]: ├─────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼─────>
Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38359]: │ 0   │ app       │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 38367    │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%  >
Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38359]: │ 1   │ config    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ N/A      │ 0      │ 0    │ stopped   │ 0%  >
Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38359]: └─────┴───────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴─────>
Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 pm2[38359]: [PM2][WARN] Current process list running is not in sync with saved list. Type 'pm2 save' to synch>
Aug 07 19:10:02 mukund-ThinkPad-E15 systemd[1]: demo-node-app.service: Succeeded.
```

but as you can see the app is still active, i cannot shut it down

can someone help me in figuring out what the issue actually is?
please help

Answer (score 2):

I also had a problem loading pm2 for non-root user on my ubuntu server causing "exit-code" failure. It was solved by this command [from here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1459):

```
su user -c "pm2 dump && pm2 kill" && su root -c "systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl enable pm2 && systemctl start pm2"
```